# table or view does not exist

Tags: powerbuilder, sybase-asa, isql

Good Day.

I'm running a Powerbuilder 9 application on an Adaptive Server Anywhere Database Engine Version 8.0.1.2600. I use a INI file to connect to the database with default user 'dba' password 'sql' and all works fine.

Right ! I want to create and use another user for the application to connect to the database. I executed a new user by using: 
sp_add_user 'alex', 'alex'; 
Then executed:
grant all on loadcon_cust to alex; (where loadcon_cust is the table name)

When I run the application using the 'alex' login, it connects to the database fine but when I access the table loadcon_cust, then PB prompts "Table or View not found: Table 'loadcon_cust' not found"

What am I missing?

Cheers, thanks in advance.

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands into ISQL:

```
GRANT GROUP to DBA;  
GRANT MEMBERSHIP in group DBA to ALEX;
```

Then try your app again.

Comment: Hi Paul.
Great, thanks, the error mssgs dissapeared. However I'm still getting a -1 retrurned from the app retrieve(). I will fiddle some more